# Xubuntu 18.04 Cannot “Apply Changes” in Software & Updates>Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, 18.04, nouveau

[image: Changing to nvidia]
[image: Result]

Hello,

I have xubuntu 18.04 this is the details of my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xubuntu1 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Currently, I have nouveau driver and I am trying to change to nvidia driver in Software & Updates- Additional Drivers when I select the nvidia option and then I click apply changes nothing happen. Do I need to do extra steps to apply this change?? I already downloaded the nividia driver from nividia's homepage and trying to install without success. Can someone help me?  I am trying to change the graphics driver because I am having problems with windows freezing and I thought the graphics driver is the problem.  Thank you so much.
PDS. This is the output of sudo apt install nvidia-304:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-304
[sudo] password for xubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 10.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                       libwayland-egl1
 nvidia-304 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-23
              Depends: xserver-xorg-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo apt install nvidia-304` terminal command to your question.

Comment: And the first screen is showing that the driver is being installed.

Comment: ready. I already added the output of sudo apt install nvidia-304

Comment: Probably `nvidia-304` is not supported on `bionic`.